# Hello World Struts 2 Eclipse project 404 error

Tags: eclipse, struts2

[image]I've created a struts2 project with eclipse, when executing it shows the message error:

HTTP Status 404 - /StrutsHelloWorld/Login.jsp
type Status report
message /StrutsHelloWorld/Login.jsp
description The requested resource (/StrutsHelloWorld/Login.jsp) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.26

I've followed step by step guide http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-create-struts-2-application-eclipse-example/
and i got that message error.
Please anybody help me!

This is the directory structure. URL: localhost:8080/StrutsHelloWorld/Login.jsp

Comment: Not enough information to help; we need to see what you're requesting (i.e., the URL), the configuration for that URL (i.e., action config), enough JSP info to know where the JSP is in relation to the web app, etc.

Comment: Nobody will help you with the provided information. post your jsp code and perhaps your project directory strucure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given url, there is full project [available for download](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/download/struts/Struts2_Hello_world.zip). And never forget to include struts2 libraries in `WEB-INF/lib`. It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

try to add the following jars into aweb-inf/lib folder and BuildPath

```
commons-fileupload-x.y.z.jar

commons-io-x.y.z.jar

commons-lang-x.y.jar

commons-logging-x.y.z.jar

commons-logging-api-x.y.jar

freemarker-x.y.z.jar

javassist-.xy.z.GA

ognl-x.y.z.jar

struts2-core-x.y.z.jar

xwork-core.x.y.z.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

I also followed the tutorial, what was missing (for me) is that I have to add the struts libraries to the deployment assembly `(project->properties->'Deployment Assembly')`

I have configured a user library as `Struts2` that contains all `struts2 jars`, I have included this entry to be deployed to `web-inf/lib`. Take a look to the console error.